# Numerical library for minimization of a multidimensional function on windows

Tags: math, numerical-methods

We need to numerically minimize a function that takes a three dimensional vector as input. The function is smooth, so a gradient algorithm would be a good choice.

However, I am used to GSL which unfortunately requires gcc. We have to work on Windows using VC++ 2010, though. I found a GSL Port for windows, but the last commit is from 2006 and I doubt that it will work with our setup.

Which libraries are there on windows and are recommended? We only have to solve this one problem, so the more specialized the library is, the better.

We are using C++, so there should be a C or C++ interface available.

Comment: I use GSL through a DLL that is supplied with it. No need for gcc at all.

Answer (score 2):

This [implementation](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/) of the L-BFGS method seems to suit your puprposes. It has also a VS2010 solution file, which makes it easy to include it into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has GSL. Depending on the nature of your restriction to Windows, perhaps that is feasible.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I never used cygwin but I thought it bundles with gcc. Since we want to include this into our projects that we compile with VC++, I don't think we can use cygwin for this. (Also there HAS to be some equivalent for windows...)

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the question to mean you needed to solve a specific problem once, not that you needed to include a solver for a particular class of problems. In that case, I don't think cygwin will do the trick, as it is based on gcc. But I'll leave the answer up in case someone with a similar question finds yours.